# How to find filed exist but empty in kibana KQL?

Tags: kibana, kibana-5, kibana-7

As title, i can't find a way to do it in kibana KQL.
I have tried NOT field, it's not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your field is a `keyword` type, the KQL query below will check for existing but empty field values:

`fieldname:""`

Note that this won't work for a `text` analysed type